# What is the formal definition of the statement that an equation is a function of one of its variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to understand what exactly it means to say that an equation that is not obviously written $f(x) = \cdots$, for instance $y - x = 1$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, is or is not a function of $x$; in particular, I'd like to know if, in general, when we say an equation is a function of one of its variable, we are mainly making a statement about the solution set of the equation

Here's my attempt. Let $S$ be the solution set of $y - x = 1$, and let $(x, y)$ designate an element of $S$. "$y - x = 1$ is function of $x$" means: For $(x,y) \in S$, there exist sets $A, B, F$ such that $x \in A$, $y \in B$, and $F \subseteq A \times B$, i.e., $F$ is a set identical to the cartesian product of $A$ and $B$, and for all $x \in A$ and for all $y,w \in B$, if $(x,y) \in F$ and $(x,w) \in F$, then $y=w$. Is this exact?

My main worry is: is it true that "$y-x=1$ is a function of $x$" is in general a statement about the solution set of the mentioned equation? Or are there other possible interpretation, when we say that an equation is a function of one of its variables?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I answered in other language,  but $F$ wouldn't be identical to the cross product, but a subset as you say.  But otherwise, your understanding is okay

Comment: We **never** say an equation is a function of one of its variables. To say an equation is a function is as sensible as to say a book is a real number, or a love affair is an orange.

Comment: "$y - x = 1$ is a function of $x$" No mathematician would say this. They might say something like "If $x$ is a real number then there is a unique real number $y$ such that $y - x = 1$.

Comment: @littleO ah that makes sense. I'm trying to find the formal statement to prove $y = \pm \sqrt{x^2-1}$ cannot be written as a function. Would it be that "the solution set of $y = \pm \sqrt{x^2-1}$ is not a function of x"?

Comment: You are on the right track.  The set $S:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|x^2+y^2=1\}$,i.e. the set of all points in the $xy$-plane that make the equation $x^2+y^2=1$ true is the same as the set of all points in the $xy$-plane that make either the equation $y=+\sqrt{x^2-1}$ or the equation $y=-\sqrt{x^2-1}$ true.  However, there is no *single* function $f(x)$ such that $S=F$ where $F:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|y=f(x)\}$, the set of all points in the $xy$-plane that make the equation $y=f(x)$ true.

Comment: @SelrachDunbar thank you so much for the help, I've spent hours on exactly this!

Comment: That's time well spent.  And, you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

We say an equation describes a function of one of its variables in terms of the others if we can uniquely define that variable in terms of the others.  In other words,  knowing what the values of the others DETERMINES the variable we want to be our function.

Example:  $x+y+z^2=3$  we can say implictly defines a function for the variables x and y, as the follows:

$$x=f(y,z)=3-y-z^2$$
$$y=g(x,z)=3-x-z^2$$
Note that plugging in y and z uniquely defines x and y.  In this case, the domain can be all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ since the original curve has all those points

However,  we cannot make this a function of $z$ because in trying to solve for $z$ we get  to
$$z=\pm \sqrt{3-x-y}$$.

Note there are now two different possible outputs for each of $x$ and $y$.  Moreover,  even if we could, we would have a limited domain,  the area in which $3-x-y\geq 0$.